# Power BI, connect directly to a dataset from a nodeJS app

Tags: node.js, powerbi, dataset, powerbi-datasource

I have an application that uses data from a DataSet in Power BI, right now, we use a flow under power automate to retrieve this data from and generated endpoint.

This is a simple question because I cannot find anything under the MS docs. Is it possible (using a connector or something similar) to retrieve the data from the dataset directly from my nodeJS app?

Note: Our app is deployed in Azure so maybe there could be an Azure function to handle that

Any guidance or docs will be highly appreciated, at least to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to register your application in the Azure Active Directory to obtain the necessary credentials (client ID and client secret) that will be used to authenticate your app when making requests to the Power BI API.

In your Node.js app, you must implement the OAuth 2.0 authentication flow to obtain an access token. This access token will be used in subsequent API calls to authenticate your app.

Once you have the access token, you can use it to make API requests to retrieve data from your Power BI dataset. You can use the "Execute DAX" or "Get Data Rows" API endpoints to get the needed data.

Once you retrieve the data from the dataset, you can process it as needed within your Node.js app.

For the documentation, you can refer to the [official Microsoft Power BI REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, you got me on the right track, just another question, Does my app registration need to be created from power BI?

Comment: No, the app registration does not need to be created from Power BI. Instead, you register your application within the Azure Active Directory  in the Azure portal.

Comment: Thank you, I'm almost there, right now I'm running tests on Postman, and the token retrieval using the tenantID, clientID and ClientSecret is working fine, but calling the Power BI API with that token is giving me a 403. So I'm still debugging.

Comment: If it is not working create another question and drop the link here :)

Comment: Hello again Amira, I've added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217700/obtain-a-microsoft-bearer-token-using-an-app-registration-and-read-from-a-datase since I'm still stuck with the authentication (the nodeJS part is no issue, but this one is though) Thanks in advance

Comment: You already have the answer ;)

Comment: I saw it, thanks again Amira, have a nice day