# Obtain a Microsoft bearer token using an app registration and read from a Dataset

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory, dataset, azure-app-registration

Following my previous question [Power BI, connect directly to a dataset from a nodeJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674126/power-bi-connect-directly-to-a-dataset-from-a-nodejs-app) I have been unable to get an access token without using user credentials.

So far I have created an app registration inside the azure AD with a client secret and the following API permissions:

[image]

Now for some reason, the account that is being used to connect to the dataset says that permission is not granted for my organization. (Not sure if I actually need that)

Is there a way to achieve retrieving this bearer token required to read a dataset from PowerBI without having to input or store a username and password within the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can make use of **client credentials** flow to get an access token
> without including user credentials.

I registered one Azure AD application named **`SriPowerBi`** like this:

[image]

Now, I created one security group and added above service principal as **member** to it as below:

[image]

Login to **Power Bi Admin** portal and enable below option by adding the security group to it under `Developer settings` like this:

[image]

Make sure to provide access to either the **service principal** or **security group** in your Power Bi workspace:

[image]

> Note that, you need to wait for **`15-20`** minutes after granting access as there will be delay and generate access token using client credentials flow.

In my case, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to read dataset details, I got **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Embed Power BI content with service principal and an application secret - Power BI | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal)

Comment: Thanks, this should work for my needs, I just need now to get tenant permissions from an Admin of the AD. But definitely, this should work.